# iteration and for loops in ggplot2 (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

like I said, I'm trying to create a for loop inside ggplot. Which I know it's hard to do and there are probably better way to do so, but I need to churn a number of these plots each with a different set of data (of different lenght) and a for loop seemed the more logical option.
The idea is to manually create a biplot, what I'm trying to do is adding the arrows from the (0,0) point to the respective end coordinates. The code so far

```
endx<-rnorm(10)
endy<-rnorm(10)
dd = data.frame(endx, endy)

g<-ggplot(dd, aes(x= endx, y= endy))+theme_bw()
g<-g + geom_point() 
  
for (i in endx) {

g <- g+ geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=0, xend=endx[i], yend=endy[i]), arrow = arrow(length=unit(.5, 'cm')))

}
g
```

but it does nothing.

Any idea?

Create a loading and or biplot using ggplot and eigenvalues extrapolated from another program.

Comment: I am unsure if this fit your need, I am removing it as an answer.

Comment: In your loop, `i` is taking random `rnorm` values .  You probably meant a for loop with values from 1 to 10:   `for (i in seq_along(endx)) {` . However, I only achieve to plot one arrow that way.

Solution: There is better way than for loop. You can provie a `geom_sement()` layer with appropriate `aes()`

    `ggplot(dd, aes(x= endx, y= endy))+
      geom_point() +
      geom_segment(aes(xend=endx, yend=endy), x=0,y=0,
                   arrow = arrow(length=unit(.5, 'cm')))+
      theme_bw()`

Answer (score 1):

`Print` is your friend, if you want a new plot for each arrow. Staying close to your syntax:

```r
set.seed(01032024)
dd = data.frame(endx = rnorm(10), endy = rnorm(10))

library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(dd, aes(x = endx, y= endy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()

for (i in seq_len(nrow(dd))) 
  print(g + geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = endx[i], yend = endy[i]), 
                         arrow = arrow(length = unit(.5, 'cm'))))
```

and in a single plot:

```r
ggplot(dd, aes(x = endx, y = endy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = endx, yend = endy), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(.5, 'cm'))) +
  theme_bw()
```

copied from the [example](https://statisticalpoint.com/ggplot-arrows/) you probably take the "code" from; gives

[image]